# R: Replace multiple strings with a single string in R

Tags: r, string, replace

I am trying to figure out how to replace multiple strings with a single string in R. For example, if I have,

`x <- c("augustt", "August", "augusT", " august", "september")`

then I want to replace all these strings with "august", except "september". I know how to do this one by one using *gsub*,

`x <- gsub("augusT", "august", x)`

but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this where you can replace all of them at once.

Comment: Try: `gsub("augustt|August|augusT| august", "august", x)`

Comment: or `gsub("augustt?", "august", x, ignore.case=TRUE)`

Comment: Wonderful! Both of these solutions work! Thank you!

Comment: You could also use `replace(x, agrepl("august", x), "august")`.

Comment: This works too! Thank you!

Comment: or: `x[-grep("september", x)] <- "august"`, or `x[!grepl("september", x)] <- "august"`

Comment: or: `x[-match("september", x)] <- "august"` ...

Comment: for this solution lets say I had other months such as "october", would it still work?

Comment: @Salahuddin the last ones are the answer to: *I want to replace all these strings ... except "september".`